# AngularJS - How to call controller function with item value as argument in ng-repeater?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am quite new to AngularJS, and I am stuck for a moment using the `ng-repreat`.

I am trying to call a controller function using `ng-click` to change the model.
First, I used the `$index` variable provided by `ng-repeat`. But when I added a filter, I could not get the correct item ID. (removing the filter restore the expected behavior)

I made a simple example : http://jsfiddle.net/folkenda/wt7b2/
As indicated in the script I would like to using `friend.id` instead of `$index` in order to set the correct value in my `friend`variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setFriend(friend.Id)` will work.   Although, you could just pass the friend object itself. `setFriend(friend)`.